# "Unclear what question you're asking"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I'd like to propose rewording of the close reason

> Unclear what you're asking

to

> Unclear what question you're asking

or some similar wording.

I think it's a better fit for closing questions that are along the lines of "My code not working", "Please write code for..." and so on.

These questions are not really questions, but requests. And Stack Overflow is a question/answer site, not request/service site.

Comment: In the [highly unlikely] even that such a question asker actually *cares* about the wording of this close reason, that'd just make them tack a, "How do I do this?" or, "Can you write this for me?" or some other variation at the end of their question.

Comment: @Servy It's mostly for the benefit of the close voter. I always feel a bit guilty when I use that reason: I know what the asker wants, so the existing wording is slightly mismatched. In the case of "Please write this for me" is crystal clear what the asker is asking FOR. But there is no question in there.

Comment: Again, at *best* that'll just make them tack, "How do I do this?" at the end (if it wasn't there already), and nothing is better, and you still have exactly the same problem.

Comment: A question _does not_ require a question mark to be a good, on-topic question.

Comment: I'd think that **ask** implies a "question", no? I can't "ask an answer"...

Comment: @brasofilo could I **ask** you to agree with me, please?

Comment: The proposed wording just adds redundancy, not clarity. If you aren't asking a question, then it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 18):

Even in the case of questions like, "How do I do this", "My code not working", or "Please write code for...", the context "question" is *implicit*.  I can't say I see any tacit benefit for the verbiage to change, since it won't change the typical communication we see on Meta:  "my question is clear, why don't you get it?"